# Coupon wrongly detects money in my cart

Tags: magento-1.8, coupon

I have two products from different category in my cart.

---

**Product |  Price |    Category**

---

Bike   |  $1000   |  Two wheeler

Car    |  $2000   |  Four wheeler

---

I have created a coupon code **OFF10 (10% off)** and set only apply to Category Two wheller.

When I apply this coupon in my cart. This should detect **$100** only, but it detects **$300**.

Can anyone helps me how to solve this problem.

**Note:**
*When I try to apply the same coupon code when I have only Car in my cart, it through error that wrong coupon code.*

Answer (score 0):

Send Some Screen Shot, I can help you with this